# Pre-processor Directive value set in the C program

Tags: c, c-preprocessor, preprocessor-directive

I would like to define something like

```
#define memoryAddress
main()
{
    bla bla bla;
    memory = endAddress- startAddress;
    #memoryAddress = memory;
}
```

Is it possible/valid way of initializing the pre-processor directive?
Basically I want to use this particular directive to update the new memory address if required. Like for eg: if it was a variable in C code I would do

```
if(memoryAddress != memory)
memoryAddress=memory
```

But since I want to use this memoryAddress as a pre-processor directive I would like to know the correct way of doing the above code. So I am going to have a default address for the directive before the compilation process begins but later I would like to update it.

Comment: No, it's not valid.  Can you explain what you are trying to do?

Answer (score 1):

Use a gloabal variable and initialize it with a default value. Then you can change it during runtime

Comment: I was going to use that, but I was just wondering if there was a way to do this way.

Comment: As others mentioned above: no it is not possible with a preprocessor directive

Answer (score 0):

Pre-processor directives are evaluated by the pre-processor and it happens ***before*** compilation.
So what you are trying to do(*assign value to a directive with something that is known at compile time and not before compilation*) is not possible.